# Apply multiple functions to a single data object - custom summary statistics

Tags: r

How can we compute descriptive summary statistics for a matrix M on a per-column basis that include mean, standard deviation, and 5%, 25%, 50%, 75%, and 95% quantiles?

This is how I would do it for the different summary statistics independently:

```
library(magrittr)    
s_1 = M %>% apply(.,2, mean)
s_2 = M %>% apply(.,2, sd)
s_3 = M %>% apply(.,2, quantiles, c(0.05,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.95))
result = cbind(s_1, s_2, s_3)
```

Ideally, I would like to wrap this functionality into a single, easy-to-understand and easy-to-maintain function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a custom function in base R that will do the trick. These are quite simple to build and alter to fit whatever stats you want:

```
myStats <- function(x) {
  myMean <- mean(x)
  mySd <- sd(x)
  myQuantiles <- quantile(x, probs=c(0.05,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.95))

  return(c(mean=myMean, sd=mySd, myQuantiles))
}
```

Now, let's test it

```
# get some data
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(100)

 myStats(x)
      mean         sd         5%        25%        50%        75%        95% 
-0.1567617  1.0044053 -1.3935761 -0.8953272 -0.3846280  0.4712061  1.7095200
```

As noted by the OP in the comments, it is possible to use this function in the `apply` family to calculate these stats over multiple variables. For example, for a data.frame, df with data in columns 3 and above (and ID variables in columns 1 and 2), you could use `sapply` to return a matrix of statistics for each column:

```
sapply(df[,-c(1,2)], myStats)
```

Comment: M <- matrix(rnorm(30, 30), ncol=3) 
M %>% apply(.,2,myStats)
--> to have the function applied to every column of the matrix.

Answer (score 3):

We can do this with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
M %>%
   as.data.frame() %>% 
   summarise_each(funs(Mean = mean, SD = sd, 
             list(Quantile = quantile(., c(0.05,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.95)))))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
M <- matrix(rnorm(30, 30), ncol=3)
```